# Как подключить к C# приложению библиотеку на C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

У меня есть .dll библиотека написанная на C++/CLI и обычное консольное приложение на C#. Я подключаю в C# в ссылки приложения ту библиотеку, прописываю using для неё, создаю объект класса и пытаюсь вызвать какой-либо метод из него. При запуске приложения, оно вылетает и вызывает ошибку:

> Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
>   "shc_lib, Version=1.0.4244.21563, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана
>   попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

В чем может быть причина ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Библиотеки на C++ - всегда платформо-зависимые, на C# же обычно AnyCPU. В итоге программа на C# может оказаться запущеной не с той разрядностью, которую поддерживает библиотека.

В качестве костыля можно сменить платформу консольного приложения, чтобы она была общей с библиотекой.

Более грамотное решение - компиляция библиотеки сразу для двух платформ, с последующей загрузкой нужной версии библиотеки. Но это потребует глубокого погружения в систему сборки.

Comment: А еще такой вопрос, подключил, все работает, но когда понижаю версию .NET Framework самого приложения на C# с 4.0 до версии 2.0 (причем версия .NET Framework библиотеки всегда была 2.0), то приложение ругается и говорит, что:
`warning MSB3258: не удалось разрешить первичную ссылку "CLRLibrary", поскольку она косвенно зависит от сборки .NET Framework "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", имеющей более позднюю версию "4.0.0.0", чем версия "2.0.0.0" в текущей целевой платформе.`
Хотя нигде нет зависимости от 4.0. Не знаете, как это можно исправить ?

Comment: @Ramon нет, этого я не знаю